# Django EmailMessage.content_type = 'html' keep newlines?

Tags: python, django, email, django-email

How can I keep new lines in a Django's `EmailMessage` that has a `content_type = 'html'`?

I need the `html` content type because of signatures.

Email:

```
Welcome User,

this is a welcome email.
```

Is rendered properly when sent as a text but when sent as an `html`, it (obviously) doesn't render newlines.

Email:

```
Welcome User,this is a welcome email.
```

I'd like to have just a plain text in my templates but I'd like them to be converted into `html` with proper newlines.

Is there a way to do that or do I need to write `html` tags myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the django.core.mail module, then I suppose you are using the [send_mail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#send-mail) method.

As described in the link, you can use the html_message parameter, but this renders HTML code, so in this case you need to add the new lines with html tags.